# Find an enclosing subfolder in Safari's bookmark hierarchy

Tags: safari, bookmarks

How do I find the enclosing bookmark folder in the hierarchy for a given bookmark on Safari/MacOS?

I looked in Xcode to examine ~Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist. That apparently doesn't hold content, just data structure info it seems. Of course I searched manually in each top level folder and then into next level enclosed folders. This problem resulted from slipping my thumb off the trackpad while trying to move a folder. It fell into some crack (ugh). I can find the contents of the enclosed folder since I recall that subfolder's name. I want the enclosing folder for a given subfolder. FWIW I saw a related question for Android's bookmark hierarchy. It doesn't seem to have been answered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Low tech answer I discovered. Go to a link that’s enclosed. Save as bookmark. Up comes a scrolling list of folders with the one enclosing it selected and also its enclosing folder. I could unravel from there.

On a related problem someone did offer a code sample.I Would have tried that but my coding skills have long since evaporated. Thanks to anyone who spent a moment considering the question.